# How to unit test vueuse/head in vitest, vue/test-utils vue3

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs3, vue-test-utils, vitest

I have this simple unit test:

```
import { describe, it, expect } from 'vitest';
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Login from './Login.vue';

describe('Login.spec.js', () => {
    it('mounts correctly', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(Login, {});
        expect(wrapper.isVisible()).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

But my Login.vue component has:

```
<script setup>
import { useHead } from '@vueuse/head';

...

useHead({
    title: 'Login',
});
</script>
```

The unit test is throwing the error:

```
[Vue warn]: injection "usehead" not found. 
  at <Login ref="VTU_COMPONENT" > 
  at <VTUROOT>
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of setup function 
  at <Login ref="VTU_COMPONENT" > 
  at <VTUROOT>
```

and

```
Error: You may forget to apply app.use(head)
 ❯ injectHead node_modules/@vueuse/head/dist/index.js:118:11
    116|   const head = (0, import_vue.inject)(PROVIDE_KEY);
    117|   if (!head) {
    118|     throw new Error(`You may forget to apply app.use(head)`);
       |           ^
    119|   }
    120|   return head;
```

How do I get past this error?

Edit: I think I have to create a local vue instance or something with my app's plugins installed, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#global-plugins

Comment: If it helps anyone, I have a similar error when attempting to use [Nuxt DevTools](https://devtools.nuxtjs.org). I've commented-out all head customizations, and unlike OP, I'm not explicitly running tests at all (although maybe NDT is?). The app runs fine when disabling Nuxt DevTools.

Answer (score 5):

I did some reading on loading in the Vue instance, and I found that:

- In vue test utils v1, you can `createLocalVue` and pass that in as a mounting option.
- In vue test utils v2, you must specify the `plugins` (described here: https://test-utils.vuejs.org/migration/#no-more-createlocalvue).

So I changed my test to this:

```
import { describe, it, expect, vi } from 'vitest';
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import { createHead } from '@vueuse/head';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';
import router from '@/router';
import Login from './Login.vue';

const head = createHead();
const pinia = createPinia();

describe('Login.spec.js', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Login, {
        global: {
            plugins: [head, pinia, PrimeVue, router],
        },
    });

    it('mounts correctly', () => {
        expect(wrapper.isVisible()).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

and it works now.

Comment: Thanks. And then, how do you assert that a certain meta tag has been set? I'm struggling cause not even `wrapper.html()` prints the `<head>` block..  i would like to check if the title and meta tags are set correctly

Comment: This fixed the error  `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')` as well for a test also interacting with primevue. This really saved me.